# what is std::array decay to in forwarding reference

Tags: c++14, type-traits, stdarray

```
template <typename T>
void test(T&& t) {
  std::cout << std::is_same_v < T, std::array<int, 2> > << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_same_v < std::decay_t<T>, std::array<int, 2> > << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_array_v< std::decay_t<T> > << std::endl;
}

void foo {

  std::array<int, 2> a;

  test(a);
}
```

What is `std::array` decaying to? The above code give me the following:

```
0  
0  // Isn't T decayed to std::array<int, 2> ?
0
```

I am very surprised by the three zeros as I thought at least either first or second would be true.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZcJFZ5tMPPgN7G8s

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your results; `std::is_same <std::decay_t<T>, std::array<int, 2>>::value` is `true` for me, as I would expect, when I run the example code you give.

Comment: This is weird. When I opened an empty file and copied the code there I can see the expected output. However, my code was running inside a project which gives me the wrong result. Let me double check.